# for loop inside jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to repeat something inside a jquery function. I tried a for loop, but it seems it doesnt like the syntax.
for instance i have the variable

```
var number = 2;
```

now i have

```
$('tr').html('<td id="'+number+'"></td>');
```

what i want to do is loop from 0 to number (0,1,2) so that in the end i end up having 3 .
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is *probably* a better way, but this should work.

```
var loops = [1,2,3];

$.each(loops, function(index, val) {
  $('tr').html('<td id="myCell' + index + '"></td>');
});
```

This should also work (regular JS):

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
  $('tr').html('<td id="myCell' + i + '"></td>');
}
```

Note how i prefixed id with the word 'myCell', to ensure XHTML compliancy. (thanks to @Peter Ajtai for pointing that out).

**EDIT**

I just noticed another problem - you're using the **.html** function to add the cells. But **.html** replaces the entire html of the matched element. So you'll only ever end up with the last cell. :)

You're probably looking for the **.append** function:

```
$('tr').append('<td id="myCell' + i + '"></td>');
```

EDIT 2 -- moved the double quote before myCell rather than after.

Comment: The for loop will work, but you should to pay attention to where you declare `i`. Additionally, those IDs are not valid. They cannot begin with numbers.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai - good point (answer updated). Wasn't paying attention to the ID's he was assigning, just the nature of the for loop.

Comment: The problem with this solution (I tried it before but tested again upon your advice) is that in the end inside the <tr></tr> there would only be one <td></td>. This is because inside the loop, the last go-around calls for only one <td><td>.

Comment: The $.each([1,2,3],...) is what I needed! That works as expected even if you create a sub-function within the loop. With a for() the sub-function is created, but the index is the current value at the time the function is called rather than the value at the time the function is created.

Answer (score 4):

Heres an option using an anonymous function.

```
$('TR').html(
    function(){
        var content=''; 
        for (var i=0; i<=2; i++  ){
            content=content+'<td id="id_'+i+'"></td>';
        }
        return content;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 loop.forEach((amount) => { 
     // your code
}
```