# jQuery iterate over each list item only once

Tags: jquery, each, preventdefault

I have a function that executes every time I scroll within the page. Within that function is an .each() function to loop through all the list items:

```
$('#scroller').on('appear', function() {
    $('#chart li').each(function(ev){
            // Do something
    });
});
```

My problem is that I only want to loop through those list items only once. I tried return false and ev.preventDefault, but then it makes the //do something apply only to the first list item.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965192/for-loop-inside-jquery-function) which is almost the same, but applying this method I am getting an "Object [object Array] has no method 'apply'" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you only want what's inside the event handler to fire only the first time it is called?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. Sorry for bad description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check if you've done it before using a variable:

```
var hasLooped = false;

$('#scroller').on('appear', function() {
    if(!hasLooped){
        $('#chart li').each(function(ev){
                // Do something
        });

        hasLooped = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: wow simple. Thanks Tom! will accept answer in 6 minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 2):

I think Tom's answer above is pretty straight forward and gives you exactly what you want. I am only offering this as an alternative or thinking in other ways.

```
// create a seperate handler for it, and then unbind once it fires.
$('#scroller').on('scroll.onceMe', function() {
       $('#chart li').each(function(ev){
            // Do something
       });
    $('#scroller').unbind("scroll.onceMe");
 });
```

or how about something like: - create a unique handler for it.

```
    $('#scroller').one('scroll.onceMe', function() {
       $('#chart li').each(function(ev){
            // Do something
       });
 });
```